# Showing the existence of a continuous function

Tags: general-topology

**Question:**

Let $A = \{ 1/n \ |\ n\in\mathbb{N} \} \cup \{0\}$. Let $\mathcal{T}$ denote the standard topology on $[0,1]$ induced by the Euclidean metric and let $\mathcal{T}_A$ denote the subspace topology on $A$ induced by $\mathcal{T}$.

a) Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence in $[0,1]$ which converges to 0. Show that the function $f(1/n) = a_n$, $f(0) = 0$ is continuous $(A,\mathcal{T}_A)\to ([0,1],\mathcal{T})$.

b) Show that for each sequence $(a_n)$ in $[0,1]$ which converges to 0, there exists a continuous function
$$
f:([0,1],\mathcal{T})\to([0,1],\mathcal{T}) \quad\text{ such that }\quad f(1/n) = a_n.
$$

**Attempt:**
I think I've solved a), but I fear I might have done something wrong since I never use the fact that the sequence converges. I simply argue that, since we can create an open neighborhood around any point in $A$ which includes no other points of $A$, that is we can write $\{ a \} = U\cap A$, where $U$ is this open interval, that all one-point sets are open in $\mathcal{T}_A$, and so all subsets of $A$ are open, and so *any* function will be continuous.

For b) I have no real idea where to start.

Comment: Does $A$ maybe include $0$? Since $f(0) =0$ and $f:A\to [0,1]$ but $0 \notin A$?

Comment: A yes, of course, I forgot that. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

For part a) you proved continuity at points other than $0$. Continuity at $0$ has to be proved separately. If $U$ is a neighborhood of $f(0)=0$ in $[0,1]$ then $[0,r) \subseteq U$ for some $r>0$ and $\frac  1 n \in f^{-1}(U)$ for $n$ sufficiently large because $a_n \to 0$. This proves continuity at $0$.

For b) the idea is to plot the points $(\frac  1 n, a_n), (\frac  1{n+1}, a_{n+1})$ and join them by a straight line. Putting these together for $n=,1,2..$ we get the graph of  a continuous function with $f(\frac 1 n )=a_n$ for all $n$.

Define $f(t)=c_nt+d_n$ where $c_n= n(n+1)(a_n-a_{n+1})$ and $d_n=a_n-(n+1)(a_n-a_{n+1})$. [$c_n$ and $d_n$ have been chosen so that $f(\frac 1 n) =a_n$ and $f(\frac 1 {n+1}) =a_{n+1}$]. Define $f(0)=0$. Note that any number in $(0,1]$ belongs to $[\frac 1 {n+1}, \frac 1 n]$ for some $n$. So this defines $f$ on all of $[0,1]$ and I will let you verify continuity of $f$.

Comment: And what about part a)?

Comment: @Peatherfed I have edited my answer.